# Troubles with LINQ and object references

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I'm stuck trying to get something along the following lines to work, here is a complete code example that can be run inside of Visual Studio that demonstrates the scenario I am talking about. Everything here works as expected, when I change the IsReady value of the player the lambda attached to the event is fired and if (to) evaluates to true. However the Console.WriteLine is never hit because it appears that the value of IsReady for the player in the ConcurrentBag is not updating.

```
class Program
{
    public static ConcurrentBag<Player> Players { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Players = new ConcurrentBag<Player>();
        Player player = new Player() { Id = "123" };
        Players.Add(player);
        player.IsReady.ValueChanged += (from, to) =>
        {
            if (to)
            {
                if (Players.All(p => p.IsReady.Value))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It worked");
                }
            }
        };

        LookupPlayerById("123").IsReady.Value = true;
    }

    public static Player LookupPlayerById(string clientId)
    {
        var player = Players.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == clientId);
        return player;
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public MonitoredValue<bool> IsReady { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {
        IsReady = new MonitoredValue<bool>(false);
    }
}

public class MonitoredValue<T>
{
    public delegate void ValueChangedHandler(T from, T to);
    public event ValueChangedHandler ValueChanged;

    private T m_Value;
    public T Value
    {
        get { return m_Value; }
        set
        {
            if (ValueChanged != null) // if invocation list is not empty, fire the event
            {
                ValueChanged(m_Value, value);
            }
            m_Value = value;
        }
    }

    public MonitoredValue() { }

    public MonitoredValue(T initialValue)
    {
        m_Value = initialValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Player` is a `class` or a `struct`?

Comment: Then you return a `reference` to a Player object. Changing it's state will affect the same object, to what a link from `ConcurrentBag<Player>` is stored

Comment: If you know of a way to do this using C# and LINQ please share. Thats the first thing I tried to do but it seems to be a limitation of the technology? Do I have to use out somehow? I was under the impression that returning FirstOrDefault() would prevent you from using references

Comment: @KennethK. I thought that this would be all the code relevant to this question although I can add more to clarify

Comment: Please share how you got to the impression "that changing things on the returned Player does nothing to the Player object sitting in the ConcurrentBag".

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster code updated to show a more complete scenario

Comment: Consider using a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: What type is `IsReady`?

Comment: `if (Players.All(p => p.IsReady.Value))`

Comment: IsReady is a custom generic class called MonitoredValue that fires an event any time an internal object's value changes

Comment: FYI `FirstOrDefault` has an overload which takes a predicate so you can do `Players.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == clientId)` instead of using `Where`.

Comment: @Lee thanks, I will probably change that for the sake of brevity

Comment: @Pretty soon I'll be posting my entire source code :P I will update the question to show my class definition

Comment: Stupid question - is the ClientId property of Player a string type, or is there some sort of implicit cast going on?

Comment: @DuncanHowe its a string, no casting

Comment: Now please the declaration of the isReady property and please tell us more about the specialization of MonitoredValue<T> there. What type is inserted for T? Is it a struct?

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster the T in this case is obviously a bool as you can see the way it has been used in the code examples above. I will post the class definition of Player to further demonstrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you first notify your listeners, and then actually change the value.
Change your property definition to code given below:

(`delegate {}` if default event implementation, now I don't need to check for null before each call)

```
public event ValueChangedHandler ValueChanged = delegate {};

public T Value
{
    get { return m_Value; }
    set
    {
        //first change
        m_Value = value;

        //now notify
        ValueChanged(m_Value, value);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I just ran your code and found that it is behaving as expected. Perhaps something is happening with the MonitoredValue that I'm missing

Comment: Please review my updated code example to see a complete and contained solution that recreates the problem

Comment: @JesseCarter Solved your issue. For me it printed `"It worked"`

Comment: Oh my gosh I can't believe I missed that... Thank you so much for your help I was going crazy trying to figure out what I was missing.

Comment: @JesseCarter it's ok, we all do these mistakes. I found that unit tests help me a lot in reducing the number of such kinds of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a reference type, Player will be referenced by the object returned by FirstOrDefault, unless it is a Default, which case you didn't get a match.

Example to demonstrate:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        ConcurrentBag<ClassA> test = new ConcurrentBag<ClassA>();
        var hurp = new ClassA();
        hurp.number = 3;
        test.Add(hurp);

        var derp = test.FirstOrDefault();
        derp.number = 4;

        Console.Write(test.FirstOrDefault().number);
        Console.WriteLine(derp.number);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Prints:
`44`

Comment: "Default" for classes is `null`, so his code would blow up in that scenario, as would yours.